# How to generate a static site with next.js 13 and supabase?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, supabase, supabase-database

I'm currently working on a project using Next.js 13 and Supabase. I've been trying to implement Static Site Generation (SSG), but every time I build, it continues to render as Server Side Rendering (SSR). Could anyone guide me on how to generate pages statically?

Below are the methods I've tried so far:

Method 1: Using GET route handler

```
// app/api/composers/route.ts
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export async function GET() {
  const res = await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL + "/rest/v1/" + "composers?select=*&order=id.asc", {
    cache: "force-cache",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Apikey': process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY
    } as HeadersInit
  });
  const data = await res.json()
  return NextResponse.json({ data })
}

// app/composers/page.tsx
export default async function ComposersPage() {
  const data = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/composers");
  const json = await data.json()
}
```

Method 2: Using fetch (or supabase client) with force-cache

```
// app/composers/page.tsx
async function getComposers() {
    const res = await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL + "/rest/v1/" + "composers?select=*&order=id.asc", {
        cache: "force-cache",
        headers: {
            Apikey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY
        } as HeadersInit,
    });
    if (!res.ok) throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
    const data = await res.json();
    return data;
}

export default async function ComposersPage() {
    const data = await getComposers();
}
```

Method 3: Using fetch (or supabase client) with getStaticProps

```
// app/composers/page.tsx

export async function getStaticProps() {
   const { data: composers } = await supabase.from("composers").select().order("id", { ascending:true });

   return{
       props:{
           composers,
       }
   }
}

export default async function ComposersPage({ composers }: { composers : Composer[] }) {}
```

Despite trying these methods, my pages still seem to be rendered server-side. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've tried implementing Static Site Generation (SSG) in my Next.js project with Supabase as described in the methods above. I expected that by following these methods, my pages would be generated statically during build time. However, despite trying these different approaches, my pages continue to render server-side instead of being pre-rendered at build time as static pages

Answer (score 0):

Pages within the app router are static by default until you use [a dynamic function](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components#dynamic-functions) or uncached fetch request.

**Documentations**:

### Dynamic functions that convert your page to dynamic rendering:

- `cookies()` and `headers()`: Using these in a Server Component will opt the whole route into dynamic rendering at request time.
- `useSearchParams()`:

  - In Client Components, it'll skip static rendering and instead render all Client Components up to the nearest parent Suspense boundary on the client.
  - We recommend wrapping the Client Component that uses `useSearchParams()` in a `<Suspense/>` boundary. This will allow any Client Components above it to be statically rendered. [Example](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params#static-rendering).
- `searchParams`: Using the Pages searchParam prop will opt the page into dynamic rendering at request time.
- Using dynamic routes without [`generateStaticProps()`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes#generating-static-params)

The next CLI provides some useful information about the static, server, and stream pages at the build time.
Run `npm run build` and see which pages are not static then go to these pages and figure out what makes them dynamic or provide the code in your question.